# Redirecting to external site on logout with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to change the page that the user is being redirected to after logging out. The thing is, I want to redirect user to the external site, so I can't use something like users_path.
I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    redirect_to 'www.google.com'     
end
```

In that case user should end up being redirected to google after logging out. And yeah, I know it seems like a weird idea.

Comment: Did you try just return `www.google.com` in `after_sign_out_path_for` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a full URL like this:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  'http://www.google.com'     
end
```

The method expects you to return a string value.

Optionally, I recommend you to read through to [the code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L190) to make sure you understand what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I was trying everything, but somehow forgot about trying the full adress with http and stuff. That helped. Thanks again.